Can I split a limit into two limits (two variable limits)?
I'm trying to evaluate this limit:
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0^{-},0^{+})} \frac{-1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$$
Can I evaluate it by splitting it?
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0^{-},0^{+})} \frac{-1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}=\lim_{x \to 0^{-}} \frac{-1}{x} +\lim_{y \to 0^{+}} \frac{1}{y} =+\infty+\infty=+\infty$$

What does the notation $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0^-,0^+)}$ mean exactly?

@GregMartin I think it means x approach 0 from the left and y from the right?

@GregMartin It means x approaches 0 from the left and y approaches 0 from the right

Taking $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0^{-},0^{+})}$ seems very strange to me. Is there even a logical way to define this? One may get very different answers depending on how $x$ and $y$ approach $0$, since it may approach $(0,0)$ as, for example, $(x,-10x)$, $(x, -0.5x)$, or $(x, \sqrt{-x})$.

@MatthewSpam - yes: $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0-, 0+)} f(x,y) = L$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x < 0, y > 0$ with $|x| < \delta, |y| < \delta$, $|f(x,y) - L| < \epsilon$. Double limits like this converge only when every way to approach the target within the domain gives the same result.

@PaulSinclair that makes sense. If this is what the poster meant, the answer should be: No, the limit in the post does not exist, since the limit would be different if we approach $(0,0)$ in different ways.

@MatthewSpam - if you were correct about it giving different results under different approaches to $(0,0)$, then indeed, it would not exist. However, none of your listed approaches gives a different result. They all yield $+\infty$ in the limit. In truth, Gatto's result is correct. And so is the approach, though it needs examined more carefully than was given here.

Oh oops my bad I read minus instead of plus.
